# Include F1000Research publication on CV

Tags: publications, cv

I am a biostatistics postdoctoral student. I recently participated in a coding festival and our work was published in F1000Research (https://f1000research.com/).

In your opinion, should I include this publication in my CV along with more typical peer-reviewed papers? Similarly, what are the pros and cons of adding this to my CV?

Thank you for sharing your thoughts!

Comment: Postdoctoral student - [the confused admin way](http://phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=1984) ;)

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I think that one should include all of one's significant scientific works in a CV.  What you do *not* want to do, however, is to give an impression of "CV-padding."

Accordingly, I recommend that you do what is done by many researchers (including myself) who publish not just in journals but in multiple different types of scientific venues: divide your publications list into different classes of publication, e.g., "Journal Articles", "Thesis Chapters", "Peer-Reviewed Conference Papers", "Non-Refereed Articles", whatever fits.

Thus, a work in something like F1000Research, which is citable archival publication but without traditional peer review, would be listed as a non-refereed article: noted as a possibly significant scientific work, but clearly labelled as different than your traditional peer-reviewed articles.

Comment: Note, however, that F1000 can be, and often are, reviewed. If the reviewers approve the paper, I would list it as peer-reviewed.